# Adaptar Height de un div que esta dentro de un td

Tags: html, css, div

Tengo un div dentro de un td,

```css
.role_color {
    display: inline-block;
    align-items: stretch;
    width: 2px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="role_color"
                             title="Prueba"
                             style="background-color: #6a1b9a"></div>
                        Nombre
                    </td>
                    
                    <td>Apellido</td>
                    <td>Pais</td>
                    
                    </tr>
```

Y lo que deseo obtener es que el div me ocupe todo el alto de esa celda

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al usar height 100% no funciona y 100vh hace que la celda se vuelva mas grande

Comment: Estoy ejecutando tu código y me funciona 100% como tu quieres, debe de quedar como en la imagen que indicas?

Comment: @DavidLeonardoMolinaRuizDav en la imagen el div no me ocupa el tamaño completo de la celda como lo marco en el recuadro rojo

Comment: Amigo nombre esta fuera del div ya que dentro del Td quiero tener el div y el nombre `<td> <div class="role_color" title="{{$userRole}}" style="background-color: {{$colorRole}}"></div> {{$r[ 'Name'] }} </td>` Ambos estan dentro del td, no se si me explico bien amigo

Comment: Yo te hice una respuesta como tu la quieres @gmrYaeL revisala

Comment: @DavidLeonardoMolinaRuizDav me funciono de maravilla, gracias!

Comment: Que bueno que te funcionara, me puedes tildar mi respuesta como valida? gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes intentar esto, hice una capa padre con la clase **.wrapper** que engloba al div con la clase **.role_color** y el texto, dicha capa ocupa el 100% de la altura y del ancho del **td** y el td le asigne una altura especifica para que el 100% de la capa **.wrapper** lo tomara, quedando como resultado esto:

```css
.wrapper{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}

.role_color {
  align-items: stretch;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: 10px;
  position:relative;
  width: 2px;
}

table tr td{
 height:50px;
 padding:0; 
}
```

```html
<table border="1" cellspacing>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="role_color" title="Prueba" style="background-color: #6a1b9a"></div>
        Nombre
      </div>
    </td>       
    <td>Apellido</td>
    <td>Pais</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Fue la solución que pude hacer, espero te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tu div ya esta utilizando el height de tu celda, por que si te fijas, solo te aparece una linea amarilla(segun tu imagen), el problema que veo es que "Nombre" esta afuera del div, por lo tanto el div tiene el limite de width hasta el contenido de la celda, si quieres que el div se extienda por toda la celda, solo modificalo asi:

```
<tr>
   <td height="50">
     <div class="role_color">
       Columna 1
     </div>
  </td>
  <td>Columna 2</td>
  <td>Columna 3</td>
</tr>
```

y tu CSS: **Edito para que sin importal el tamano de tu celda, el div se adapte a todo y el contenido(texto) quede siempre alineado con las otras columnas**

```
.role_color {
display: inline-block;
align-items: stretch;
margin-right: 10px;
height:100%;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
background-color: #6a1b9a;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Avisanos si es eso lo que necesitas hacer. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Las celdas se adaptan al tamaño del contenido y no al revés, si dices que el div no ocupa el 100% de la celda es porque la celda tiene `padding` o el div tiene `margin` y la solución sería quitárselo

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.border {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.celdasSinPadd td, .celdasSinPadd th {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="border">Contenido</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="celdasSinPadd">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="border">Contenido 2</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Me funciono la opcion de quitar le padding a la celda, solo que al colocarle al div la propiedad height:100 % no me muestra el div